# Porque devo manter arquivos de áudio e vídeo dentro da pasta raw?

Tags: android

No Android tem-se dentro do diretório `res` vários subdiretórios, separados, aparentemente, para melhor organização. As vezes quando se quer colocar um novo áudio, por exemplo para toque, diferente dos padrões do dispositivo, é aconselhado colocar numa pasta chamada `raw`.

Porque devo manter arquivos de áudio e vídeo dentro da pasta `raw`? Existe alguma tratamento especial para que tenhamos que mante-los dentro deste diretório? Existe alguma consequência ou perda de performance ao colocar um arquivo de áudio dentro do diretório `drawable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ferramentas do SDK do Android compilam os recursos(*resources*) juntamente com o binário da aplicação<sup>(1)</sup>. Durante esse processo são gerados símbolos(classe R) para cada um, afim de poderem ser acedidos no código.

A classe R contém código para todos os recursos na pasta *res/*. Para cada tipo de recurso, há uma subclasse R (`R.drawable`, `R.layout`, etc.) e, para cada recurso daquele tipo, um número inteiro (id) que o identifica.
O *id* é usado, no código, para referenciá-lo, quando se pretende utilizar o recurso.

Para permitir esse mecanismo o Android tem uma estrutura de pastas pré definida e obriga a que cada tipo de recurso seja colocada na pasta respectiva dessa estrutura.

Assim, não é uma questão de "**devo**" ou "**performance**" mas sim a forma como o Android trata os recursos da aplicação que obriga a que cada [tipo de recurso](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) seja colocado na pasta respectiva.

<sub>(1)

- Os arquivos colocados na pasta *res/raw* não são compilados, são apenas geradas entradas na classe R.

- Os arquivos colocados na pasta *java/assets* não são compilados e não será gerada qualquer entrada na classe R.</sub>

Referências:

- [Acesso aos recursos.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)
- [Fornecimento de recursos.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)
- [Resources.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)
- [Resource Types.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)

Comment: Considerando a frase "Os arquivos colocados na pasta res/raw não são compilados[...]", então se eu colocar um arquivo de áudio no diretório, por exemplo layout, esse arquivo será compilado? Ou arquivos de mídia não são compilados de forma alguma?

Comment: O gradle não permitirá a existência de um arquivo áudio na pasta *layout*. Experimente e veja o que acontece.